# Problems receiving data from a record for update operation (Trying to access array offset on value of type bool)

Tags: php

I can't get my `form_update_manga.php` page to receive the values from the records that the `form_read_manga.php` page sends.

None of the fields return any value from the record, making it impossible to update the form. By the way, there is no way to do anything in this form. I can't find a logical solution.

The error that occurs in the form_update_manga.php page is shown in the figure below:

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj0nh.png)

Error in most form fields: **Trying to access array offset on value of type bool**

- `Manga.php`

```
<?php
    
    require_once '../model/BD.php';
    
    class Manga extends BD {
        
        private $id_manga, $title, $publisher, $volumes, $discount, $value;
        
        public function getId() { return $this->id_manga; }
        public function getTitle() { return $this->title; }
        public function getPublisher() { return $this->publisher; }
        public function getVolumes() { return $this->volumes; }
        public function getDiscount() { return $this->discount; }
        public function getValue() { return $this->value; }
        
        public function setId($id_manga) { $this->id_manga = $id_manga; }
        public function setTitle($title) { $this->title = $title; }
        public function setPublisher($publisher) { $this->publisher = $publisher; }
        public function setVolumes($volumes) { $this->volumes = $volumes; }
        public function setDiscount($discount) { $this->discount = $discount; }
        public function setValue($value) { $this->value = $value; }
    }
?>
```

- `MangaDAO.php`

```
    protected $table = 'manga'; 
    
    public function readManga() {
        try {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE id_manga = :id_manga";
            $stm = BD::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
            $stm->bindValue(':id_manga', $this->getId());
            $stm->execute();
            return $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error PDO" . $e->getMessage();
            die();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error" . $e->getMessage();
            die();
        } 
    }
    
    public function updateManga() {
        try {
            $sql = "UPDATE $this->table SET title = :title, publisher = :publisher, 
            volumes = :volumes, discount = :discount, value = :value WHERE id_manga = :id_manga";
            $stm = BD::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
            $stm->bindValue(':id_manga', $this->getId());
            $stm->bindValue(':title', $this->getTitle());
            $stm->bindValue(':publisher', $this->getPublisher());
            $stm->bindValue(':volumes', $this->getVolumes());
            $stm->bindValue(':discount', $this->getDiscount());
            $stm->bindValue(':value', $this->getValue());
            return $stm->execute(); 
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error PDO" . $e->getMessage();
            die();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error ". $e->getMessage();
            die();
        } 
}
```

- `form_read_manga.php`

```
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px;">
        <h4 class="text-center">Manga list</h4>
        <br>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Publisher</th>
                    <th>Volumes</th>
                    <th>Discount</th>
                    <th>Value collection</th>
                    <th>Register date</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        require_once "../model/MangaDAO.php";
                        $manga = new MangaDAO();
                        foreach ($manga->readAllMangas() as $value){
                            echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td>'.$value['id_manga'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$value['title'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$value['publisher'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$value['volumes'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$value['discount'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>R$'.$value['value'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($value['register_date'])).'</td>';
                                echo '<td>';
                                    echo '<a class="btn btn-info" href="/mangas/view/form_update_manga.php?id_manga='.$value['id_manga'].'"role="button" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;Update</a>';
                                    echo "&nbsp;";
                                    echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="/mangas/controller/delete_manga.php?id_manga='.$value['id_manga'].'"role="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Delete</a>';
                                echo '</td>';                  
                            echo '</tr>'; 
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

- `form_update_manga.php`

```
    <?php
    
        require_once "../model/MangaDAO.php";
    
        $mangaDAO = new MangaDAO();
        
        if (!isset($_GET['id_manga'])) {
            echo '<p><a href="../view/form_read_manga.php"><button>Redo operation</button></a></p>';
            die();
        } else {
            $data = $mangaDAO->readManga($_GET['id_manga']);
        }
            
    ?>
        <div class="container" id="t_container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <h4 class="text-center">Update collection</h4>
            <small class="form-text text-muted text-center">All fields are mandatory</small>
            <br>
            <form method="POST" action="/mangas/controller/update_manga.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>ID:</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="id_manga" required value="<?php echo $data['id_manga'] ?>" disabled>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Title:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" required maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $data['title'] ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Publisher:</label>
                  <select class="custom-select" name="publisher" required value="<?php echo $data['publisher'] ?>">
                        <option selected value="">Choose the publisher</option>
                        <option value="Astral Comics" title="Astral Comics">Astral Comics</option>
                        <option value="Clamp" title="Clamp">Clamp</option>
                        <option value="Conrad" title="Conrad">Conrad</option>
                        <option value="Darkside Books" title="Darkside Books">Darkside Books</option>
                        <option value="Devir" title="Devir">Devir</option>
                        <option value="JBC" title="JBC">JBC</option>
                        <option value="NewPop" title="NewPop">NewPop</option>
                        <option value="Nova Sampa" title="Nova Sampa">Nova Sampa</option>
                        <option value="Panini" title="Panini">Panini</option>
                        <option value="Pipoca & Nanquim" title="Pipoca & Nanquim">Pipoca & Nanquim</option>
                        <option value="Veneta" title="Veneta">Veneta</option>
                        <option value="Other" title="Other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Volumes amount:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="volumes" required onkeypress="$(this).mask('000', {reverse: true});" value="<?php echo $data['volumes'] ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Discount:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="discount" required onkeypress="$(this).mask('000.00', {reverse: true});" value="<?php echo $data['discount'] ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Value collection:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="value" required value="<?php echo $data['value'] ?>" onkeypress="$(this).mask('000.00', {reverse: true});">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="btn_update" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;Update</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this in **MangaDAO.php**

```
protected $table = 'manga'; 

public function readManga($mangaId) {
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE id_manga = :id_manga";
        $stm = BD::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
        $stm->bindValue(':id_manga', $mangaId);
        $stm->execute();
        return $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error PDO" . $e->getMessage();
        die();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error" . $e->getMessage();
        die();
    } 
}
```

Comment: It's almost right, only the ```Publisher``` field that doesn't return the value corresponding to the record, could look more closely at this field?

Comment: You have to put selected attr to specific value please refer the below code:

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the selected attr to a specific value please refer to the below code.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Publisher:</label>
    <select class="custom-select" name="publisher" required value="<?php echo $data['publisher'] ?>">
        <option value="" <?php if($data['publisher']==''){echo 'selected';} ?>>Choose the publisher</option>
        <option value="Astral Comics" title="Astral Comics" <?php if($data['publisher']=='Astral Comics'){echo 'selected';} ?>>Astral Comics</option>
        <option value="Clamp" title="Clamp" <?php if($data['publisher']=='Clamp'){echo 'selected';} ?>>Clamp</option>
        <option value="Conrad" title="Conrad" <?php if($data['publisher']=='Conrad'){echo 'selected';} ?>>Conrad</option>
        <option value="Darkside Books" title="Darkside Books" <?php if($data['publisher']=='Darkside Books'){echo 'selected';} ?>>Darkside Books</option>
        <option value="Devir" title="Devir" <?php if($data['publisher']=='Devir'){echo 'selected';} ?>>Devir</option>
        <option value="JBC" title="JBC" <?php if($data['publisher']=='JBC'){echo 'selected';} ?>>JBC</option>
        <option value="NewPop" title="NewPop" <?php if($data['publisher']=='NewPop'){echo 'selected';} ?>>NewPop</option>
        <option value="Nova Sampa" title="Nova Sampa" <?php if($data['publisher']=='Nova Sampa'){echo 'selected';} ?>>Nova Sampa</option>
        <option value="Panini" title="Panini" <?php if($data['publisher']=='Panini'){echo 'selected';} ?>>Panini</option>
        <option value="Pipoca & Nanquim" title="Pipoca & Nanquim" <?php if($data['publisher']=='Pipoca & Nanquim'){echo 'selected';} ?>>Pipoca & Nanquim</option>
        <option value="Veneta" title="Veneta" <?php if($data['publisher']=='Veneta'){echo 'selected';} ?>>Veneta</option>
        <option value="Other" title="Other" <?php if($data['publisher']=='Other'){echo 'selected';} ?>>Other</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again, the publisher field is working as it should.